# function in model receive the message ** Is not a function **

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, mysql2

I have a project with NodeJS, Express and Sequelize(mysql2)...
I don't understand, he whats talks **is not a function**.
I create model and set this function from model, how below follow

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Scheduling = sequelize.define("Scheduling", {
        ... //attributes
    });

    Scheduling.associate = ( models ) => {
        ... defined relashionships.
    };

    /**
     * date,
     * hourBegin,
     * hourEnd,
     * employeeId,
     * clinicRoomUUId,
     * institutionId
     * */
    Scheduling.prototype.haveAppointments = (date, hourBegin, hourEnd, employeeId, clinicRoomId, institutionId) => {
        return Scheduling.findOne({
            where: {
                date,
                employee_id: employeeId,
                clinic_room_uuid: clinicRoomId,
                hourEnd: {$gte: hourBegin, $lte: hourEnd}
            }, institution_id: institutionId
        });
    };

    return Scheduling;
};
```

And I call this function in my SchedulingController:

```
...
let scheduling = await Scheduling.haveAppointments(date,hourBegin, hourEnd, employeeId, clinicRoomId, institutionId);
if(scheduling) {
   return res.status(401).json({scheduling, message: `Já existe um apontamento realizado para este dia e hora!`})
}
...
```

and when I run the api call and it goes through this section it says that `Scheduling.haveAppointments` **is not a function**

*Stacktrace do node...*

```
    at create (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/src/app/controllers/SchedulingController.js:10:43)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/hugo/Hugo/cvvfj-core/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:294277) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:294277) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Indeed, `Scheduling.haveAppointments` is not the same thing as `Scheduling.prototype.haveAppointments` (which you defined). With `prototype`, the idea is that you have an *instance* of  `Scheduling`, and then call that method. But if `Scheduling` is not a constructor, then probably you should not have that `.prototype` there at all.

Comment: Thanks @trincot, you helped me a lot ... Maybe, I think I understand, how to use Prototype! lol, I should only use it when I instantiate new object (model).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, for `let scheduling = await Scheduling.haveAppointments(...)` statement, you are calling the static method on `Scheduling` model class.

But you declare the function as `Scheduling.prototype.haveAppointments`, this is the instance method of the `Scheduling` model class.